# Abp Boilerplate Abp.Feature.AllFeatures to C#

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using abp boilerplate.
On my Client side I read out the Features and set new values. How can I save these Features to my database.

On Client side Features are correctly but what is the type for these Features on my backend in asp.net

I have tried for example:

```
public List<IFeatureDefinitionContext> Licences { get; set; }
public Dictionary<FeatureValueStore, Feature> LicencesList { get; set; }
public List<FeatureSetting> LicencesSetting { get; set; }
public List<Feature> LicencesTest { get; set; }
public List<FeatureDictionary> LicencesDictionary { get; set; }
```

On Client side:
get values:
    $scope.licenceValues = abp.features.allFeatures;

edit values and save:

```
appService.saveLicences($scope.licenceValues);
```

here I tried a Little bit with licences licencesList, Settings etc

```
var saveLicences = function (licences) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            abp.ui.setBusy(
                null,
                localizationService.saveLicences({
                    licences: licences,
                    licencesList: licences,
                    licencesSetting: licences,
                    licencesDictionary: licences
        })
                .success(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                    abp.notify.success(abp.utils.formatString(localize("ConfigSaved"), ''));
                }).error(function (response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                })
            );
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

and in my application.dll project these values should be shown...

Answer (score 0):

Though I cannot understand your question clearly; I guess you need the definitions of features, so you can inject and use `IFeatureManager`.

Please see https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Feature-Management

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
I'm using abp.features.allFeatures in my JavaScript function. Now I wanna save the new Features, set in my js Code to the database but which type should I choose in C#
abp.features.allFeatures = C# List or Dictionary etc